Is this proof of $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_n}{b_n} = \frac ab $ wrong?
In class we first proved that for a sequence {$b_n$} converging to b, $ \frac{1}{b_n} \to \frac 1b$  ( provided b is not equal to 0). Then we used the result $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n$ = ab to prove that $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_n}{b_n} = \frac ab $.
My proof is as follows-
$$ a=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n  =  \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\frac {b_n}{b_n}  =  \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n  \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {a_n}{b_n} = b \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}.$$
So, $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac ab.$
What is wrong here?

What makes you think that there is something wrong? $\quad$ Are you asking for your proof to be verified, esp given the tag that you're using? If so, please read the tag for instructions.

@CalvinLin My teacher said it is wrong. And yes I think I would also like it to be verified because I am not able to see any proof going along the same lines as mine.

@DietrichBurde  Ok. Otherwise it's alright?

@DietrichBurde Thank you very much. So if I just write it this way my teacher will not have a problem right?

@DietrichBurde Ok. Thank you very much for your help.

When you go from $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\frac {b_n}{b_n}  =  \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n  \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {a_n}{b_n}$ you skipped the middle step$ \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\frac {b_n}{b_n}  =\color{green}{\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n\frac {a_n}{b_n}}=  \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n  \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {a_n}{b_n}$. Now the only thing wrong with the proof is you assume $\lim \frac {a_n}{b_n}$ actually exists in the first place.

Style wise though your proof has too much indirect detours.  If you know $\lim c_nd_n =\lim c_n\cdot \lim d_n$ (assuming you know the limits exist) and you know $\lim \frac 1{b_n} = \frac 1{\lim b_n}$ then just not: $\lim \frac {a_n}{b_n}=\lim a_n\cdot \frac 1{b_n} = \lim a_n\cdot \lim \frac1{b_n} = a\cdot \frac1b = \frac ab$.

@fleablood Aren't these results supposed to hold for convergent series only? If so, isn't it implicit that the limits of an and bn exist?

I didn't want to use $a_n, b_n$ as that would sound like I was talking about specific $an,b_n$ of the problem.  Let me start again. You have proven two propositions. 1: If $\lim a_n=a;\lim b_n=b$ then $a_nb_n$ converges and $\lim a_nb_n=ab$. Prop 2: if $b_n\ne 0$ and $\lim b_n = b\ne 0$ then $\frac 1{b_n}$ converges and $\lim\frac 1{b_n}$. So my point is if you know those two propositions then $\lim \frac {a_n}{b_n}=\lim a_n\cdot \frac 1{b_n} = \lim a_n\cdot \lim \frac1{b_n} = a\cdot \frac1b = \frac ab$. That's all you have to do.  It seems like you took too many twists.

@fleablood Yes, I understand now. Thank you very much for you help.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\frac {b_n}{b_n}  =  \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n  \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {a_n}{b_n}$$
This step is wrong. You can only use $\lim x_ny_n=\lim x_n\lim y_n$ if you know that both sides on the right hand side exist. Otherwise, it may lead to problems. For example, say $a_n=1$ and $b_n=n$, then your equation reads
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$$
which is obviously false.
Now, you might object that my example is not really a contradiction since $\lim n$ does not exist. But again that is because, it is proven that if $\lim a_n$ exists and $\lim b_n$ exists and is nonzero, then $\lim a_n/b_n$ does exist. But you cannot use this in your proof, so the equation at the top of my answer needs at least the existence. Hence, your proof shows that if $\lim(a_n/b_n)$ exists, then it has to be $a/b$. But the existence needs to be shown.
Hope this helps. :)

This might sound dumb but I do not know why that statement is obviously false.

In the hope of forestalling confusion, it might be worth editing to clarify that "This step is wrong" means, "In the context of the question, this step assumes what is to be proven" or something similar (rather than "This step is always false" or something similar).

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n$ does not exist.  $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n = 0$.  So you have $1 = \text{something that does not exist} \cdot 0$ which is false.  This concept is sometimes treated niavely as $\infty \times 0 =1$ and treated niavely (mostly by me when I was a child) as though it were true, but it's.... meaningless and badly defined.

@Pumpkin_Star: It is okay, and that is false because $\lim_{n\to\infty}n$ does not exist, so the equation does not make sense.

@Pumpkin_Star The key is both ${b_n}$ and ${a_n/b_n}$ need to converge, so take $a_n=1/n, b_n=1/n^2$.

' But again that is because, it is proven that if lim an  exists and lim bn exists and is nonzero, then lim an/bn does exist. But you cannot use this in your proof,...' --- I am confused here. We already know that an is converging to a and bn is converging to b right?  Because my teacher said that these results that we are proving hold true only for convergent sequences. Infact we have proven anbn---> ab using the definition of convergence wherein we used the fact that an--->a and bn--->b

@Pumpkin_Star: In short, when you break the limit into $\lim b_n$ and $\lim(a_n/b_n)$, then you assume that $\lim(a_n/b_n)$ exists, which needs to be shown.

You know $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge.  But you don't know (until you prove it) that $\frac {a_n}{b_n}$ converges.

@ultralegend5385 Thank you. I understand now.

@fleablood thank you very much.

As an alternative, by the definition $\forall \varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2>0$, assuming wlog $a, b >0$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n=ab \iff \exists n_1\;\forall n\ge n_1\; |a_nb_n-ab|<\varepsilon_1 \iff ab-\varepsilon_1<a_nb_n<ab+\varepsilon_1$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{b_n}=\frac1b \iff \exists n_2\;\forall n\ge n_2\; \left|\frac1{b_n}-\frac1b\right|<\varepsilon_2\iff \frac1b-\varepsilon_2<\frac1{b_n}<\frac 1 b+\varepsilon_2$$
then $\forall n\ge \max(n_1,n_2)$
$$\left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}-\frac ab\right|=\left|a_nb_n\frac{1}{b_n^2}-\frac ab\right|< \left|(ab+\varepsilon_1)\left(\frac 1 b+\varepsilon_2\right)^2-\frac ab\right|=$$
$$=\left|2a\varepsilon_2+ab\varepsilon_2^2+\frac{2\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2}b+\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2^2\right|$$
which can be small of any fixed $\varepsilon >0$ since $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2>0$ can be arbitrarly small, and therefore $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to \frac a b$.
